# relative path not working on local server but works on remote server

Tags: php, apache-2.2

I have this image link that works on remote server but doesn't work on local server.

```
 //Remote Server Works

        <img src="../behind_wwwroot/img_folder_fast/cars.jpg">
```

---

```
//Local Server doesn't work

    <img src="../behind_wwwroot/img_folder_fast/cars.jpg">
```

Local server dir tree

www/my_server

Apache Document root and Directory set to C:/wamp/www/my_server

Image files exist in C:/wamp/www/behind_wwwroot/img_folder_fast/cars.jpg

I want to put uploaded images behind www root for obvious reasons.

Anybody pls help

Comment: what are the permissions of 'behind_wwwroot' on the local machine?

Comment: what are the permissions on the file? 9 secs faster @DTest, nice. Linux command: ls -ltr behind_wwwroot behind_wwwroot/img_folder_fast behind_wwwroot/img_folder_fast/cars.jpg

Comment: The folder has Read/write/Execute permissions alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else going on.

The web browser with translate the relative URL into an absolute one and then request it. As such you cannot access files outside the www root.

A webpage on example.com:

```
<img src="../folder/file.jpg" />
```

Will translate to a request for:

```
http://example.com/folder/file.jpg
```

More specifically. You cannot request a file outside of the example.com www root. If however your web page was in a folder (e.g. example.com/mywebsite/) then this could work.

What reasons do you have for having the images outside of the www root? If you think you can access them anyway what advantage does it have? If you MUST have them outside the www root you need to have the server redirect requests using either PHP or some .htaccess rules.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This is so a hacker can not gain access and delete all user uploaded images.